# How to find which plugin is outputting Open Graph tags to <head>

Tags: wp-head, open-graph

After getting an error the Facebook debugger about duplicate og:url tags, I'm trying to find which plugin is outputting the second set of Open Graph tags to my `head` section.

I've tried deactivating each plugin, then viewing the source page using incognito mode in Chrome but that hasn't helped find the source of the issue.

Any other ideas or should I be looking somewhere else?

The site in question is http://marchforkids.org. The code I want to remove is on lines 91-95 in the source of the front page.

Comment: If it's not a plugin, maybe it's your theme?

Comment: @AndrewBartel I originally didn't consider that because I didn't see any admin-facing options for customizing the Open Graph tags but I am going to take another look. Thank you!

Comment: I had the same problem before and solved it with a simple research in the php source of the plugins and themes I was using. If you haven't tried that yet, get all your files from the server into a local folder and search for a match with the problematic tag.

Comment: Maybe you got caching enabled?

Comment: @AndrewBartel You actually solved it, along with Olivier's thought about searching the files locally. Found it in an uncommented section. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Do a search inside:

```
var_dump( $GLOBALS['wp_filter']['wp_head'] );
```

Then just do a crossfile search for the attached callbacks.